# Looping through a viewmodel and updating a value in my C# MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have a view model:

```
public class RatesViewModel
{
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public long TypeID { get; set; }
    public int TypeCount { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<Occ> Occs { get; set; }

}
public class Occ
{
    public string occ { get; set; }
    public decimal ratetocharge { get; set; }
    public int numOfOcc { get; set; }
    public virtual RatesViewModel RatesViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

This populates a var "rooms".

Based on some condition, I want to update the Occ.ratetocharge - for example, change them all to deduct 50:

```
  foreach (var r in rooms)
        {
        // do a query which looks up a value from another table
        if (conditionMet == true)
        {
             r.Occs.ratetocharge = r.Occs.ratetocharge - 50;
        }
        }
```

However,

```
r.Occs.ratetocharge
```

...isn't allowed.  So I'm wondering how to update the ratetocharge?  Is my viewmodel setup wrongly, or is there a better way of doing what I want to achieve?

Thank you for any advice,

Mark

Comment: This is just a C# question, it has nothing to do with ViewModels, MVC or Entity Framework. You are just trying to modify properties on a collection, which can't be done without iterating over each item in the collection explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do something like this

```
if (conditionMet == true)
{
    foreach(Occ occ in r.Occs)
    {
        occ.ratetocharge = occ.ratetocharge - 50;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Index number

```
  r.Occs[Index].ratetocharge - 50;
```

or use loop

```
foreach (var r in rooms)
        {
        // do a query which looks up a value from another table
        if (conditionMet == true)
           {
       foreach(Occ occ in r.Occs)
           {
         occ.ratetocharge = occ.ratetocharge - 50;
           }       
          }
        }
```